# Автоматический f5

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет. Как можно перезагрузить страницу средствами `JavaScript` (или из `AJAX`'а)? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location = "http://mysite.ru"

Comment: @DemoS, я бы хотел редирект на **свой** сайт. А что делать если адрес неизвестен? Или есть ли что-то типа `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: 1. @DemoS Лучше не window.location.href = "http://mysite.ru"
2. @alex_90 Вы хотите сделать редирек на свойт сайт, а адрес не знаете? )) Это что-то новое.

Comment: @Deonis, я имел в виду, что можно `GET`-ом прицепить туда *что-то*, а `JavaScript` не знает об этом. И поправьте меня если я неправ, но ссылку можно переписать как `location.href = "/"`.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам без адреса на jQuery:
 $(function(){
location.reload();
});

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, у меня почему-то вызывает зависание :-(

Comment: Кошмар)) @alex_90, и вы не понимаете, почему?)

Comment: @Sh4dow, если честно - нет.

Comment: @alex_90 

 - сайт загружается, начинают выполняться скрипты.
 - страница переадресовывется
 - сайт загружается, начинают выполняться скрипты.
 - страница переадресовывется
 - сайт загружается, начинают выполняться скрипты.
 - страница переадресовывется
 - сайт загружается, начинают выполняться скрипты.
 - страница переадресовывется

а так?)

Comment: @Sh4dow, ну я же не на пустом месте ставлю его. А вешаю его на событие. А window.location у меня почему-то работает правильно.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, @Sh4dow. Господа, а вы уверены что в Internet Explorer'е это сработает?)))

Answer (score 0):

**replace** - никто не отменял. И с параметрами и без. *"... а JavaScript не знает об этом..."* - главное, чтоб вы об этом знали )))

```
alert("Сейчас вы будете автоматически перенаправлены!");
location.replace('http://hashcode.ru/questions/83514/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-f5');
```